ucsi_acpi error con1: failed to get usb role switch, PPM init failed
after the motherboard on my laptop was replaced, I get following errors during early boot:
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ENODEV: con1: failed to get usb role switch
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ENODEV: PPM init failed

as far as I can tell, usb-c ports are working fine. but I would like to understand what these errors mean, and how to get rid of them.
Is this perhaps just some UEFI bios setting that needs to be disabled/ enabled?
The settings were reset to factory defaults during the replacement, obviously.

The firmware claims the laptop supports an ACPI interface for communicating with the USB Type-C Platform Policy Manager (PPM), which is responsible for negotiating things like Type-C alternate modes and battery charging/power delivery over USB Type-C.
But when the kernel actually tried to access the interface to gain access to Type-C role switch functions (e.g. to switch from plain USB to USB+DisplayPort, or to decide if the port should allow fast-charging a tethered mobile phone from the laptop or not), the ACPI interface did not respond within a 5-second timeout. This is probably a firmware bug.
If the firmware-based Platform Policy Manager works well enough, everything Type-C related might still work; it's just that the kernel/OS will have no way to influence the Platform Policy Manager. For example, the kernel/operating system/you might want to allow fast-charging of any tethered mobile phones only when the laptop has its own AC power supply plugged in, or only when it's your phone.
Check the UEFI firmware version ("BIOS version"): it might be different/older than what the laptop's original motherboard had. Update if necessary.
References:

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/usb-type-c-ucsi-spec.pdf (the actual specification)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/ucsi (a concise description on how it integrates with the rest of the USB ecosystem [in Windows, though])
https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TYPEC_UCSI.html (the relevant Linux kernel configuration item for UCSI in general...)
https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/UCSI_ACPI.html (... and for the ACPI interface for it specifically)

